# Array incrementation using other arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Below is my code for a simpleish array problem, i have to put a string into an array (done) and then scan the array for unique words, place them into a separate array, and count how many individual unique words there are in the string in the 3rd and final array. I can get it to print out the string but it and count each word but not unique ones. I believe the problem is in the if statment, or the uwords incrementation.
Any help appreciated but i would rather hints to the answer rather than just the answer if possible!

```
String[] words = text.split(" ");

String[] uwords = new String[words.length];
int[] wordcount = new int[words.length];

 for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
            for(int e = 0; i<words.length; e++){ //loop to count individual words
                if(words[i].equals(uwords[e])){ //If word in array is contained in the unique words arrary then increment
                    wordcount[wordcounter] = wordcounter+ 1;
                }else{ //else (word is not contained in uwords) add to uwords and increment
                    uwords[e] = words[i];
                    wordcount[i] = wordcount[ + 1];
                }

            }

            System.out.println(uwords[i] + ": " + wordcount[i]);
```

Pesudocode is:

```
    Find unique words:
    Create unique word array
    Create unique word count array 
    For every word in text
        if word exists in unique word array
            Increment corresponding count in unique word count array 
        else
            Add new unique word in unique word array
            Increment corresponding count in unique word count array 

List all unique words
```

Comment: Over the cuckoo the blueberry flies, and under the toll bridge the hash pie lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all

```
  for(int e = 0; i<words.length; e++)
```

is an endless loop

there is a much easier way to do this. just use a set (`Set<String> set = new Set<String>()`)
go through the words array once and add all of them to the set, it will automatically just add words that aren't already inside.

you can then proceed to call every Item in the set with a for each loop for output.
it also has a length attribute to get the amount of words.

Comment: I think i need to do it using arrays, i've added the pesudocode if it helps! also changed that infinite loop so e<words.length

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the usage of two or more "parallel" arrays, in which elements on corresponding indexes make for a single object, is a bad design practice.

I'd try to use a `Map<String, Integer>`, in which each key is a unique word, and its associated value is its count. Then, the loop will be simple:

```
Map<String, Integer> uWords = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
    String uWord = uWords.get(words[i])
    Integer count = uWords.get(uWord);
    if(count != null){
        count++;
    }
    else{
        count = 1;
    }
    uWords.put(uWord,count);
}
```

Then, you can handle your `Map` in a thousand ways to find what you need.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, im doing a first year programming course and we've just been introduced to arrays so its nothing that advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing the pseudocode, it makes it easier to answer. The problem is that

```
    if word exists in unique word array
        Increment corresponding count in unique word count array 
    else
        Add new unique word in unique word array
        Increment corresponding count in unique word count array
```

does not correspond to

```
    for(int e = 0; i<words.length; e++){ //loop to count individual words
            if(words[i].equals(uwords[e])){ //If word in array is contained in the unique words arrary then increment
                wordcount[wordcounter] = wordcounter+ 1;
            }else{ //else (word is not contained in uwords) add to uwords and increment
                uwords[e] = words[i];
                wordcount[i] = wordcount[ + 1];
            }

        }
```

You need to *first* loop through all the words in `uwords` to evaluate the boolean expression `word exists in unique array` and *then* do the if statement.